# initialise an NSArray with an unknown size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

Once an Array is initialized, in order to set value of desired position, I am using

```
[self.appName replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[self.appCell objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

Problem is that if I initialize appName array without objects, this array keeps empty and I must initialize it using initWithObjects and then works. Problem is that I do not know the size of an array and if I set it like:

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test",@"test",@"test",@"test", nil];
self.appName = nameArray;
[nameArray release];
```

For example, works from 0 to 3 but from position 4 to following ones, after replaceObjectAtIndex, position has a nil value. How to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *mutable* array, you can add objects (to the end) and insert objects (in the middle) as well, whenever you like:

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[nameArray addObject:@"test"];
[nameArray insertObject:@"another test" atIndex:0];
[nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

You can do this anywhere you have a pointer to the mutable array.

Comment: [self.appName insertObject:[self.appCell objectAtIndex: 0] atIndex:x]; working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the count methon on [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) it gives you the number of elements in the array. So check that your index x is less than the count then you can remove the element.